# Fastest way to store and save coordinate data in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, opencv, mediapipe

I getting face landmarks for each frame in a video. There are `477` landmarks, and each one is a `(3,)` vector.

I have a 10 minute video at 30 fps. This means that I have `18000` arrays of shape `(477,3)`. I want to store all this info in a pandas dataframe where each row is a frame and has 477 columns, one for each (3,) array.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
frame_lms = []
for frame in video:
    landmark_dict = {}
    lm_count = 0
    for landmark in frame:
        x = landmark.x
        y = landmark.y
        xy = np.array([x,y])
        landmark_dict[f"lm_{count}"] = xy
        lm_count+=1
    frame_lms.append(landmark_dict)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(frame_lms)
df.to_csv('save.csv')
```

I got the idea to store everything in a list of dicts, append to a list, and then save from research showing that `from_dict` is the fastest way to create a pandas df. However, this process is still slow because I have to hold `frame_lms` in state, which gets huge as I append `(477,3)` arrays into it.

What is the most computationally efficeint way to solve a problem like this?

Comment: There's a typo here: ```landmark_dict[f"lm_{count}"] = xy``` should be ```lm_count``` in the curly brackets

Comment: Have you tried to create a numpy array in or pandas dataframe in advance and then store the values?

Comment: @azelcer is appending into a numpy array faster than appending into a list?

Comment: I propose not to append, but to create the array in advance: `rv = np.empty((len(video, 477, 3))` and then set the values using the indices. I think you might be spending too much time creating objects.

Comment: don't use pandas. use numpy, store binary data. your data is one big matrix. there's zero reason to use dicts or anything complex.

Comment: It seems that each landmark is only a (2,) vector, right? I see only `x` and `y `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to avoid creating and converting to `numpy.array` many objects in the inner portion of nested a loop. Your code is much faster if you change `xy = np.array([x, y])` in the inner loop to `xy = (x, y)`. In the following code, I left the conversion to `numpy.ndarray` out since I understand it is OK for the OP.

Since python is very efficient managing lists you can create a list of lists with the data, and asign the column names when creating the `DataFrame`.

The faster, *pythonic* way of creating the list is

```
rv = [[(lm.x, lm.y) for lm in f] for f in video]
```

The it is equivalent to the following, slightly slower code (not recommended):

```
import numpy as np

# load video here

rv = []
for frame in video:
    internal = []
    for landmark in frame:
        internal.append((landmark.x, landmark.y))
    rv.append(internal)
```

You can create the `DataFrame` from the lists using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rv, columns=[f"lm_{count}" for count in range(477)])
```

Comment: Thanks. I have this working but how do I save it into a dataframe now? When I run `pd.Dataframe(storage)`, it breaks with the error: `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(18000, 477, 2)`

Comment: To reiterate, I want a df of 18000 rows, 477 columns, and each element is the (2,) array.

Comment: I see what you want. Creating many `numpy.ndarray`s in the inner loop is expensive. Does tuples of length 2 (instead of arrays of length 2) serve to your purposes?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why that wouldn't be okay. How should I proceed?